# Integral of $1/(1+x \tan(x))^2$

Tags: integration

How would you solve the following integral?

$$\int \frac{1}{(1+x\tan(x))^2} dx$$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just am not able to get that first substitution.

Comment: Do you have some reason to think there's a closed-form solution? The much simpler-looking $\int x\tan x\,dx$ doesn't.

Comment: It came in my test. So, I guess it should be a high school level problem. Unless, they made a mistake :o. xD

Answer (score 13):

A substitution works...
$$
\frac{1}{(1+x\tan x)^2} = \frac{\cot^2 x}{(\cot x+x)^2}
$$
and
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\;(\cot x+x) = -\cot^2 x
$$
so ... you finish it.

Answer (score 2):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Let $\displaystyle I = \int\frac{1}{(1+x\tan x)^2}dx = \int\frac{\cos ^2x}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}dx$

So $\displaystyle I = \int \frac{\cos x}{x}\cdot \left\{\frac{x\cos x}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}\right\}dx$

Now Using Integration by Parts....

So $\displaystyle I = -\frac{\cos x}{x}\cdot \frac{1}{(x\sin x+\cos x)}-\int \frac{(x\sin x+\cos x)}{x^2}\cdot \frac{1}{(x\sin x+\cos x)}dx$

So $\displaystyle I = -\frac{1}{x\cdot (1+x\tan x)}+\frac{1}{x}+\mathcal{C} = \frac{\tan x}{(1+x\tan x)}+\mathcal{C}.$